# Runtime explanation of this function

Tags: asymptotics, runtime-analysis

I am trying to understand the runtime complexity of the below code in terms of n.

I know that it is $Θ(n^{4/3})$, but I don't get why.

I thought the outer loop runs $log(n)$ times, the second one runs $n^{1/3}$ times and the innermost runs $O(log(n))$ times as it runs $i$ times and $i$ is at most $log(n)$. This would add up to $log^2(n)*n^{1/3}$, right?

```
for (int i = 1; i ≤ n; i = 2 ∗ i) {
    for (int j = 1; j∗j∗j ≤ n; j = j + 1) {
        for (int k = 1; k ≤ i∗i; k = k + i) {
            f();
        }
    }
}
```

( `f()` runs in constant time)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The analysis leading to $\Theta (\log^2 n \cdot n^{\frac{1}{3}})$ looks right. So, the $\Theta (n^{\frac{4}{3}})$ claim looks wrong.

Comment: Careful: the number if iterations of the inner-most loop depends on $i$. Translate the loops into sums (cf. [our reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)) and simplify. (cc @Gassa -- that rough upper bound on the inner loop doesn't necessarily lead to that $\Theta$!)

Comment: Hint: Factor out the sum over $j$; it's independent of the other two. Rewrite the rest as $\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} \sum_{k=0}^i \bigl[ (2^k - 1) \cdot 2^i + 1 \bigr]$ (add proper rounding to $\log n$). Why? Now simplify using standard formulae.

Comment: Ow, thanks @Raphael! I see now the trap I've fallen into. Indeed, the innermost loop runs 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... times depending on `i`, instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... times as I mistakenly thought.